# Optimization/Jensens Inequality

Tags: optimization

A community has a fixed stock $X$ of oil that it has to consume over an infinite horizon. The utility function to be maximized is
$$U=∑_t \delta^t \ln (C_t)$$
where $C_t$ represents consumption of the resource at time $t$. Also $\delta_t \in [0,1]$ is the discount factor for time $t$. Find the optimal consumption of at time $t$.

I have tried to apply Jensen's inequality  since $\delta^t \ln (C_t)$ will be a concave function, but cannot figure out how to go beyond that.

Comment: That thing totally didn't render right in mathjax.

Comment: i tried my best to represent what you wanted to write in intelligible MathJax. Please check...

Comment: It sounds like you want to pick the function $C_t$ to maximize $U$ while satisfying $\int_0^\infty C_t dt = X$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes..that will be correct..thanks

Comment: I suppose you meant that the discount factor is $\delta^t$.  If so, you can solve this optimization problem using Lagrange multipliers.  I got $C_t = \delta^t (1-\delta) X$.

Comment: Hi JHF, i am not familiar with Lagranges that involve integral constraints (or functions).Would be very grateful if you can show how to set up the lagrangian..thanks